# How do I remove console output from an ed command?

Tags: bash, ed

I'm using **ed** to insert contents in a file at a particular line number. This is the code section of my **ed** command.

```
ed servertest << END
$LineNumber      #15i
$Text            #this is text
.
w
q
END
```

The above code works fine and prints the text onto the file at the specified line number. However, I am getting an output on the console each time I run the code. For example:

```
$ bash code.sh
1456
1534
```

I think these numbers represent the number of characters in the file, servertest. I realise I do have 1456 characters in the un-edited file before running the code and 1534 characters after running the code. **Is there a way I can not have these numbers shown on the console?** I tried directing the output to `dev/null` but **ed** does not allow any characters after the last END command.

Comment: Does `ed -s` do the trick?

Comment: @dave it does! post it as an answer so i can accept it, thanks :)

Comment: Though `ed -s` is the right thing to do here, please notice that adding a `>/dev/null 2>&1` will generally ignore both *stdout* and *stderr*.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein would you advice that I use `>/dev/null 2>&1` over `ed -s` ?

Comment: No. There's no reason to do that when `ed` supports that internally.

Comment: ... If you're interested in redirections and want to read more, I suggest you to take a look here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ed's *silent* option, ie:

```
ed -s servertest << END
...
```